# UIPopoverPresentationController Fade In

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

In my iOS8+ project, I am presenting a UIViewController using UIPopoverPresentationController:

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
vc.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
vc.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.someView.superview;
vc.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = self.someView.frame;
vc.popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
vc.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp | UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown;
vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 500);
```

(Also implementing the delegate method to force as popover)

```
-(UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller
{
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```

Currently, it appears instantly over the presenting UIViewController (and disappears with fade out). Can anyone direct me towards customizing this presentation so I can make it fade in?

Comment: you can try https://github.com/AugustRush/ARTransitionAnimator for UIViewController transition animation

Comment: @Madangupta thanks. Will do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to achieve the effect, by simply setting:

```
[self.view setAlpha: 0.0];
[self.popoverPresentationController.containerView setAlpha:0.0];
```

in the popover viewController's `viewWillAppear:` method, and then calling

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{

    [self.view setAlpha:1.0];
    [self.popoverPresentationController.containerView setAlpha:1.0];

} completion:nil];
```

in the `viewDidAppear:` method.

Comment: I tried your method, i do not think it great, do you think?

Comment: I've done the fade in animation in `prepareForPopoverPresentation:` and replaced the fade out animation in `popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover` (and then dismissed with no animation in my animation's completion). This also looks better with the popup's arrow fade out.

Comment: @Geva that definitely makes the solution better looking.

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggest:

---

```
 - (void)showRight:(NSString*)title{
    UIButton *rightBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    rightBtn.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    rightBtn.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 44);
    rightBtn.titleLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    [rightBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightBtn setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    rightBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment=UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight;
    [rightBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickRight:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightBtn];


}


-(void)onClickRight:(UIButton *)bar{

    NSLog(@"bubble");
    POPViewController *popVC = [[POPViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *destNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:popVC];/*-> Here popVC is a controller you want to show in popoverview *******/
    popVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(280,200);
    destNav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    _dateTimePopover8 = destNav.popoverPresentationController;
    _dateTimePopover8.delegate = self;
    _dateTimePopover8.sourceView = self.view;
//    _dateTimePopover8.sourceRect = CGRectMake(0, 64, 70, 44);// CGRectMake(SCREEN_W-20, 64, 70, 44);;//->Here  Rect  is you want show position


    // ->here I got  the rightBarButtonItem position and  show
    CGRect frame = [[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem valueForKey:@"view"] frame];
    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y+10;
    frame.origin.x = frame.origin.x+15;
    _dateTimePopover8.sourceRect = frame;


    destNav.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    [self presentViewController:destNav animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (UIModalPresentationStyle) adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController: (UIPresentationController * ) controller {
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}

-(void)hideIOS8PopOver
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

---

I hope I could help you!

Comment: Does this make the popover fade in instead of appearing instantly?

Comment: change:
popVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(280,200); 
  ---> 
 popVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(20,30);

and change :
[self presentViewController:destNav animated:YES completion:nil];
---->
[self presentViewController:destNav animated:YES completion:^{
        
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            popVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200,300);
        }]; 
    }];

***************************
did  you   want  see  this  style ?

Comment: fixing one bug for  answer : ************************************************
popVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200,1);
*******************************************************************************
[self presentViewController:destNav animated:NO completion:^{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
            popVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200,300);
        } completion:nil]; 
    }];

Comment: Please edit your existing answer instead of posting a comment.